# how to change only the display of value of a select in angular not the actual view

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I have created a select a select in angular as:

```
<select ng-model="addAppointment.timeSlot" name="timeSlot" class="custom-back" ng-disabled="!addAppointment.date" ng-options="timeSlot1 as timeSlot for timeSlot in availableTimeSlots | getSlotTime" required>
</select>
```

here the `availableTimeSlots` contains time in 24 hour clock format.

and the `getSlotTime` filter converts the time to 12 hours format:

```
    app.filter('getSlotTime', function() {
    return function(input) {
        var array = [];
        angular.forEach(input, function (value) {
            array.push(moment(value, 'hh:mm').format('hh:mm A'));
        });
        return array;
    };
});
```

now I want the select to show the time as `08:30 PM` but it's value should be `20:30`

Comment: any error you are gettting?

Comment: no my api is expecting value in 24 hours format.

Answer (score 2):

change the format to 12 hours like this

```
 array.push(moment(value, ["h:mm A"]).format("HH:mm"));
```